# Ctags with Rails not working

Tags: ctags

I have installed ctags (Ubuntu 16.04), added `set tags=./tags;` to `.vimrc` file, it kinda works, I can move around ruby classes and methods I have defined myself but when I want to see Rails built-in sources definitions it does not.

For example, when I press `ctrl+]` having the cursor under `Post.new` in my controller it works, it takes me to the definition of the Post class in post.rb file. When I position the cursor on `has_many` method it does not work, it throws an error (translated from polish) `E426: Can't find indicator: has_many`.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my problem myself by installing the gem [gem-ctags](https://github.com/tpope/gem-ctags) and followed the instructions included there. In order to keep the tags up-to-date install [vim-bundler](https://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler) plugin, which automatically alters the tags to include all gems after executing `bundle` command.